# Consolidate multiple columns in df to single column based on value / Nested np.where unknown depth

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe that contains columns like this - `['labels', 'labels.1', 'labels.2']` this continues to some number `labels.n`

One of these columns contains a value I need. I want to grab that value and add it to `df['final_label']`. If the value is not in the labels columns, the new column should be blank.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
|  Age  |  City  | labels | labels.1 | labels.2 | labels.n |
| ----- | ------ | ------ | -------- | -------- | -------- |
|   27  | city A | value1 |  other   |  other   | other    |
|   45  | city B | other  |  other   |  value2  |          |
|   34  | city A | value2 |  other   |  other   | other    |
|   57  | city D | other  |  value2  |          |          |
|   30  | city E | other  |  other   |  other   |          |
```

I need the final dataframe to look like this:

```
|  Age  |  City  | labels |
| ----- | ------ | ------ |
|   27  | city A | value1 |
|   45  | city B | value2 |
|   34  | city A | value2 |
|   57  | city D | value2 |
|   30  | city E |        |
```

I realize a nested np.where() will have an unknown depth so not sure how to implement that in a simple way.

Here is what I have been trying to do:

```
labels_cols = [col for col in df.columns if "labels" in col]
        
values_list = ['value1', 'value2']
        
### I want to basically do this, but the depth is unknown
df['final_labels'] = np.where(df['labels'].isin(values_list), df['labels'],
                        np.where(df['labels.1'].isin(values_list), df['labels.1'],
                           np.where(df['labels.2'].isin(values_list), df['labels.2'],
                              np.where(df['labels.n'].isin(values_list), df['labels.n'],''))))

### Tried some things like this, but can't get the syntax right
df['final_label'] = df.loc[df.index(values_list), df.columns.str.contains('label')==True]
```

Comment: Kindly share sample input dataframes with expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy thanks I just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fillna with another series, wich uses that series to fill the null values. Assuming all columns used to fill the labels column contain "labels.":

```
values_list = ['value1', 'value2']
df.loc[~df["labels"].isin(values_list), "labels"] = np.nan
for c in df.columns:
    if "labels." in c:
        df.loc[~df[c].isin(values_list), c] = np.nan
        df["labels"] = df["labels"].fillna(df[c])
        del df[c]
```

Then `df["labels"]` contains the result.
Updated to filter the values with "value list". This answer assumes you want to drop the columns, if not, you need to initialise `df["final_labels"]` first, remove the `del df[c]`, and then use the columns that contain `"labels"`.

Comment: Sorry I did not include this in my initial input df - but there are other values mixed in, not just nan's. Just updated question.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Thanks @DeepKling! does this line df.loc[~df["labels"].isin(values_list), "labels"] = np.nan find all columns with substring 'labels' in column name?

Comment: No, this uses loc to filter the column "labels" for values that are not (~) in values_list and then sets the column "labels" to np.nan. I filter the columns containing "labels." inside the for loop, you could also use a list comprehension like `for c in [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("labels.")]:`

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` to keep `labels` columns then replace unwanted values by `nan` before forward fill values until the last column:

```
pattern = r'^(?!value1|value2)$'
df['final_label'] = df.filter(like='labels').replace(pattern, np.nan, regex=True) \
                      .ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].fillna('')
print(df)

# Output
   Age    City  labels labels.1 labels.2 labels.n final_label
0   27  city A  value1    other    other    other       other
1   45  city B   other    other   value2               value2
2   34  city A  value2    other    other    other       other
3   57  city D   other   value2                        value2
4   30  city E   other    other    other                other
```

Comment: sorry I did not include this in my initial input df - but there are other values mixed in, not just nan's. Just updated question.

Comment: @Joe. See my update ;-) I had anticipated this case

Comment: Thank you @Corralien! I am getting this error though "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds"

Comment: Just try `df.filter(like='labels').replace(pattern, np.nan, regex=True).ffill(axis=1)`. What is the output?